# git merge is not adding a file from branch A to branch B and says that it's already up to date

Tags: git, version-control, merge

so branch-A has

```
src/fileA
```

branch-B has

```
src/filaA
src/fileB
```

when i do `git checkout branch-A` and then `git merge Branch-B` it says `Already up-to-date` and nothing happens, it does not add the file from B to A.

Also i don't know if this is relevant, but `branch-A` was made from a previous commit from `branch-B`

Kind of like this:

```
     B
    /         
---A0---A1(deleted and added some stuff here)---A
```

and I'm trying to merge B with A to add the stuff deleted in `A1` while keeping stuff added from `A1`

Comment: Obviously you didn't commit.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi what commit did I not do? checking github.com i can see that both branches are in the state in which i mentioned

Comment: check what is already merged : what does `git log --graph --oneline --decorate branch-A branch-B` tells you ? (or use some graphical viewer to view the state of `branch-A` and `branch-B`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what a merge does.

A merge does not *just* merge branches, it merges *changes* introduced on these branches.

Let's see what you've done.

1. You had B
2. Then you branched out A
3. You did stuff on A, like delete a file
4. Then you try to merge B into A

You are now hoping to bring back the file you deleted. This is not what a merge will do. A merge will try to merge changes done on B *after* you created A into A.

If you modify the file on the B branch, and then try to merge you would get a merge conflict since the file was deleted in one branch and modified in another.

If you haven't modified the file in the B branch since you created A, then A wins the merge regarding this file, the file stays deleted.

This is how merging is supposed to work.

If you want to bring back the file on the A branch you should (partially) revert the commit that deleted it.

Comment: `If you want to bring back the file on the A branch you should (partially) revert the commit that deleted it.` Not good enough, reverting does bring back the file but also removes changes done in A which i want too. However your answer clarified it for me, i just needed to make a "dummy" commit on B (just added 1 line to whatever file), this way B would be ahead of A and i could effectively merge them, get the merge conflict and resolve it to do what i want. Not sure if that's the "right" way to go about it but it worked, thanks!